# Confused - which shell do I really have?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cygwin

The commands which I ran and their outputs are given below -

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ whence bash
sh: whence: command not found

$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

I am not sure which shell I really have. First one says bash and the second says sh.
So, which shell is it ? bash or sh ?

Comment: May I know why I got a -1 ? Please tell me how I can fix the question. This question did not get a -1 for so long, so it seems that its ok.

Comment: Please move this question to superuser (and also give me a +1 if you can :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should clarify what you are using:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

Comment: yes, that gives me the version. lets try that with echo $CSH_VERSION
...no result

Comment: Meaning you are running BASH.

Comment: can you give me a +1 if thats ok ?

Comment: That's not the way it works. You'd rather ask a moderator to move your question to Superuser where it belongs. It is off topic as you are not  asking in the context of a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that /usr/bin isn't a link to /bin or vice-versa and that /usr/bin/bash isn't a link to /bin/bash or vice versa.  It is possible that you are running one binary, /bin/bash, but that your path lists /usr/bin before /bin, in which case, `which bash` would list /usr/bin/bash - but that only means that /usr/bin/bash is the one you will run if you type `bash` on the command line.  It doesn't mean it is the one you're running.